# Why does Gmail not reconnect faster?

Tags: http, web-applications, gmail, websocket, socket.io

When [Gmail](https://mail.google.com/) loses the connection, it displays messages such as:

> Not connected. Connecting in 3:36… [Try now]

Would faster reconnect intervals really be that big of a deal?

I am asking because I am developing a [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/) based mobile web app,
and I want to avoid having a message as on Gmail. Instead I imagine a
scheme such as:

- reconnect at fast random intervals between one second and a minute,
  *plus*
- reconnect on certain user interaction, *plus*
- reconnect on change of [browser state](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/offline.html#browser-state).

Comment: Note that Gmail doesn't use Websocket. For all the support Google has given to WS they strangely don't support it on their platforms/apps (app engine, docs, gmail etc).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Please note, though, that this question is not specific to Websocket. I added the *Websocket* tag, because 1. I assume that developers of Websocket based apps are familiar with issue, and 2. my app is based on Socket.IO which includes Websocket as possible transport.

Comment: I know, hence posted that as a "comment" as in, additional information that doesn't target to answer your question ;)

Answer (score 1):

One reason why your application loses connection to the server could be that the server or the connection to the server is overloaded. Spamming it with reconnection attempts could make the situation worse.

In the end, it depends on your usability requirements. When the user spends a long time in an email program, he is usually not interacting with it constantly but is reading a single email. Also, a mail client can live with being disconnected for several minutes, because it isn't unusual for emails to be read with a latency of several hours after they got sent. So GMail can live with longer delays before attempting to reconnect. When you have an application where the user is constantly interacting with the server, you might prefer shorter delays for reconnection attempts.

Comment: thanks for your thoughts! What you say makes sense to me. I don't think that server-overload is a big issue in my case. If that happens, then user experience will be bad anyhow, and the app is nothing mission critical. It's a game, where hiscores are transmitted via Socket.IO.